# Launcher with long middle dock button

Tags: htc-desire, cyanogenmod, launcher

One thing I miss about HTC Sense is that their launcher button had an elongated middle button for the dialer. Is there a launcher or dock that replicates this kind of UI?

(I'm using CM 7.1 RC1 on an HTC Desire.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CyanogenMod uses ADWLauncher by default, so one option would be to simply use a [Sense theme for ADW](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.androidfeens.htcsenseadwtheme).